# Not able to to move two objects in opposite directions simultaneously in openGl

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glut

I am trying to make a project where we can move one tank in one direction ,other in the opposite direction by using **translatef** function I am able to move tank 1 ,when I try moving tank2 both the tanks start moving in the same  direction along with the background .
Here is the image:-[image]
Here when i click "**Move Russian tank**".It is moving .When i click **Ukrainian tank** i want it to move in opposite direction. I am not able to move Ukranian tank in opposite direction .Can u help with this ?.
Here is my code snipet:-

```
float th = 0.0;
float trX = 0.0, trY = 0.0;
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (rFlag == 1) //Rotate Around origin
    {
        trX += 0.5;
        trY += 0.0;
    }
    background();
    tank2();
    glTranslatef(trX, trY, 0.0);
    if (rFlag == 2) {
        trX = 0.0;
    }
    tank1();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void rotateMenu(int option)
{
    if (option == 1)
        rFlag = 1;
    if (option == 2)
        rFlag = 2;
    if (option == 3)
        rFlag = 3;
}
void tank1()
{
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-479, -429);
    glVertex2f(-479, -359);
    glVertex2f(-399, -359);
    glVertex2f(-399, -429);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-459, -389);
    glVertex2f(-459, -379);
    glVertex2f(-419, -379);
    glVertex2f(-419, -389);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-459, -399);
    glVertex2f(-459, -389);
    glVertex2f(-419, -389);
    glVertex2f(-419, -399);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-459, -409);
    glVertex2f(-459, -399);
    glVertex2f(-419, -399);
    glVertex2f(-419, -409);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-459, -359);
    glVertex2f(-459, -329);
    glVertex2f(-419, -329);
    glVertex2f(-419, -359);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-439, -329);
    glVertex2f(-419, -289);
    glVertex2f(-414, -289);
    glVertex2f(-434, -329);
    glEnd();
}
void tank2()
{
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(391, -309);
    glVertex2f(391, -239);
    glVertex2f(471, -239);
    glVertex2f(471, -309);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(411, -279);
    glVertex2f(411, -264);
    glVertex2f(451, -264);
    glVertex2f(451, -279);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(411, -279);
    glVertex2f(411, -294);
    glVertex2f(451, -294);
    glVertex2f(451, -279);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(411, -239);
    glVertex2f(411, -209);
    glVertex2f(451, -209);
    glVertex2f(451, -239);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(431, -209);
    glVertex2f(451, -169);
    glVertex2f(456, -169);
    glVertex2f(436, -209);
    glEnd();
}
int background()
{
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//Green
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-600, -800);
    glVertex2f(-600, -100);
    glVertex2f(800, -100);
    glVertex2f(800, -800);
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: And what does the button click do? Can you share the code for that? Also, make sure that you are posting a [mre].

Comment: @kiner_shah Button click are the various menu's to perform actions .Move Russian tank moves the russian tank and so on..

Comment: I mean where is the code for moving the tanks?

Comment: @kiner_shah Its in display function

Answer (score 0):

You need to have separate positions for both tanks *and* a separate mechanism for updating their position. Let us apply a smattering of OO:

```
struct Tank {
  float x = 0, y = 0;
  float dx = 0, dy = 0;
  std::function<void()> drawFunc;

  void update() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
  }
  void startMoving(float dx_, float dy_) {
    dx = dx_;
    dy = dy_;
  }
  void stopMoving() {
    dx = dy = 0;
  }
  void draw() {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(dx, dy, 0);
    drawFunc();
  }
};
```

That means we can now declare the following somewhere global:

```
Tank tank1{0, 0, 0, 0, &draw_tank1};
Tank tank2{0, 0, 0, 0, &draw_tank2};
```

Your display function is now simply:

```
tank1.update(); tank1.draw();
tank2.update(); tank2.draw();
```

And you need to call `startMoving` or `stopMoving` on the correct tank in response to inputs, of course.

As a first improvement you should make the `x` and `y` positions match the positions of the tanks on screen and rewrite the `draw_tank` functions to draw around (0,0).